# Typescript and Redux - Errors Working with Visual Studio 2017's default app layout

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, typescript, redux, react-router

So I'm creating a web form for requesting that mobile applications be developed.   This form will take info about mobile applications from users and save it so that developers can review the request later.

I don't have a ton of familiarity with Redux and Typescript, but I decided to go with the VS React template project to save time starting work on this, and that uses React, Redux and Typescript.  Still, so far I haven't had any issues.  I've created a listing page, and have started working on a page that lets you actually create a new request.

The request creation page is reached via React Router.  It's listed specifically as a route, and there is a link in the page navigation which lets you bring up the creation page. Here's the creation page:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState }  from '../store';
import * as AppRequestStore from '../store/AppRequest';
import DeveloperAccounts from './DeveloperAccounts';

type CreateAppRequestProps =
    AppRequestStore.AppRequestState
    & typeof AppRequestStore.actionCreators
    & RouteComponentProps<{}>;

class CreateAppRequest extends React.Component<CreateAppRequestProps, {}> {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.Continue = this.Continue.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        // This method runs when the component is first added to the page
        this.props.create();
    }

    Continue(e:any) {
        this.props.begin();
    }

    public render() {
        let content;

        if (!this.props.appRequestBegun) {
            content = <div>
                <p>Please have all relevant info ready for reference before beginning the app request process.</p>
                <p>
                    {this.props.currentAppRequest ? this.props.currentAppRequest.CurrentSectionId : ''}
                </p>
                <p>
                    {this.props.currentAppRequest ? this.props.currentAppRequest.AppRequestSections.map(thing => thing.SectionType.Name) : ''}
                </p>
                <button value="Continue" onClick={this.Continue}>Continue</button>
                </div>
        }
        else
        {
            content = <DeveloperAccounts />
        }

        return <div>
            <h3 className="elementor-icon-box-title">Create App Request</h3>

            {content}
        
        </div>;
    }
}


// Wire up the React component to the Redux store
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.appRequest, // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
    AppRequestStore.actionCreators                 // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props
)(CreateAppRequest) as typeof CreateAppRequest;
```

This works fine!  I'm able to access the Redux state, which successfully hits a backend API to bring live data into the page, all that jazz.  It all works fine so far.  But now I'm wanting to add my first subcomponent to this page, and I'm

running into errors which I don't understand. That's the  component reference in the creation page.

DeveloperAccounts is just a dumb component with some bare HTML in it right now.  I haven't done anything else because I just wanted to have a working subcomponent inside the creation page before adding the real stuff.  All I did was take a copy of the creation page and rename the key variables (class name, etc.):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
import * as AppRequestStore from '../store/AppRequest';

type DeveloperAccountsProps =
    AppRequestStore.AppRequestState
    & typeof AppRequestStore.actionCreators;

class DeveloperAccounts extends React.Component<DeveloperAccountsProps, {}> {
    constructor() {
        super();

    }

    public render() {
        return <div>
        Developer Accounts
            
        </div>;
    }
}

// Wire up the React component to the Redux store
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.appRequest, // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
    AppRequestStore.actionCreators                 // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props,
    
)(DeveloperAccounts) as typeof DeveloperAccounts;
```

This gives me the following error:

ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/CreateAppRequest.tsx:64:17 
    TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNo...'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.
    Property 'appRequests' is missing in type '{}'.

appRequests is a property of the main application state, which is part of the props type for this class.  The error makes it seem to me like the component is expecting everything in applicationState to be passed to it, but I don't know how that would happen.  I don't have any props to pass to the component, and I just want it to be wired up to the main application state anyway with the connect method, just like the creation page was.

I did make one change to the props interface for this component. The creation page's props type also included RouteComponentProps<{}>, I assume because that page is referenced by the router.  But since this child component isn't included as a route, I thought the route component props shouldn't be included.

Anyway, I have no clue why this seemingly simple component throws such inscrutable errors.  I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Uhh...I guess I just found a solution for this, but it seems...not right.  The error goes away when I pass the creation component's current props to the DeveloperAccounts component like so:  <DeveloperAccounts {...this.props} />      But this seems like an antipattern to me.  Why on earth would I have to pass the props from a component, when those props are just coming from the shared ApplicationState in the Redux store in the first place?  Instead of passing these universal values from a parent component to a child, shouldn't I just have both of them be referencing the Redux store?

Comment: ...and yeah, that solution does not seem like a real fix.  It seems like it only actually gets the live props the first time it's created, but after a re-render it's losing that data.  Still lost on what to do.